# Closing pop-up (ish) button on selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[image]

I have webpage I am trying to crawl some data. But in order me to navigate the page, I have a pop-up ish button (like a coupon button on e-commerce webpage) that I need to close.

I have taken several approach.

1. switch_to does not work, as there is only one page.
2. so I did the brute force way. finding all clickable buttons.

```html
buttons = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'button')
links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
input_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//input[@type="button" or @type="submit" or @type="reset"]')

# Find elements with 'onclick' attribute
onclick_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@onclick]')

# Find elements with a cursor style of 'pointer' in their CSS
css_pointer_elements = [element for element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*') if element.value_of_css_property('cursor') == 'pointer']

# Combine all elements
all_clickable_elements = buttons + links + input_buttons + onclick_elements + css_pointer_elements

# Now you can iterate over all clickable elements and interact with them
for element in all_clickable_elements:
    print(element)
    try:
        # If the element is not displayed or disabled, then Selenium can't interact with it
        if element.is_displayed() and element.is_enabled():
            element.click()  # Click the element
            print("Element clicked!")
            driver.back()  # Go back to the previous page after each click
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Couldn't click the element: {e}")
```

which surprisingly did not work as i thought one of these would close the button for sure.

If this button had a text, it would be easy to find, but it marked with in image 'x' so I cannot find any hints to go about it.

I am not familiar to web dev, (my work is mainly data science and i wanted to try data crawling) so any help/hints/little explanation of web development ideas would be much appreciated.

*** Update : Here is the html element.

```
<button class="MyTicketTooltip_button_close__1PV-1"><svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="MyTicketTooltip_icon_close__21V7d" aria-hidden="true"><path stroke="#DADDE0" stroke-width="1.5" fill="none" d="M1.072 1.519l15.567 15.568m0-15.568L1.072 17.087"></path></svg><span class="blind">안내 닫기</span></button>
<svg width="18" height="18" viewBox="0 0 18 18" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="MyTicketTooltip_icon_close__21V7d" aria-hidden="true"><path stroke="#DADDE0" stroke-width="1.5" fill="none" d="M1.072 1.519l15.567 15.568m0-15.568L1.072 17.087"></path></svg>
<path stroke="#DADDE0" stroke-width="1.5" fill="none" d="M1.072 1.519l15.567 15.568m0-15.568L1.072 17.087"></path>
```

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I have. Is this what you were talking about ?